# PySpark Parallelism during the write

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying the write the data to partition folder based on the affected date like below

```py
    for affect_dt in str_dt:
        df_final.filter(F.col('dt') == affect_dt)
                .repartition(1) \
                .write \
                .mode("overwrite") \
                .parquet(".../table/dt="+affect_dt)
```

But the job is running sequentially. Is there a way to execute the job in parallel

Note: I cant use `.partitionBy('dt')` because it delete the entire data and then writes

Comment: what about filtering first `df_final.filter(F.col("dt").isin(str_dt))` then repartitioning by `dt`?

Comment: i have source and delta that would be reconciled  after the processing I rewrite data back to the source for affected days . But Spark limitation is that i cant overwrite only affected dt . So i have collected the affected dt in an array(str_dt) . Later for each day i processing back